# Use intent to play several video files in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, video, playlist

I am trying to play videos in the user's default video player. I want them to play one after another (like a playlist). Currently I know how to play only one (see the code below). Can I open a folder or list of files ?

Here's my code:

```
final Intent playIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
playIntent.setType("video/*");
playIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(playIntent, "Play videos list"));
```

Comment: try using m3u8 list  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5866/is-there-a-way-to-open-an-m3u8-playlist-on-android

Comment: ps . there are libs for playlist & queues on android mobile if you take slightly largerview of framework ( include chrome, webapp )  examples https://github.com/googlecast/cast-manager-polymer/blob/master/queue-manager.html   OR https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/android/libraries/cast/companionlibrary/cast/MediaQueue.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I know how to play only one (see the code below)

That will not necessarily play a video. That is `ACTION_SEND`, and many, if not most, video player apps will not be expecting that `Intent` structure. VLC, for example, does not support this. `ACTION_VIEW` is *far* more common here.

> Can I open a folder or list of files ?

Not really. A small percentage of video player apps support `ACTION_SEND`. An even smaller percentage of video player apps support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. There is no equivalent for `ACTION_VIEW` to view a collection of items.

Comment: So my best option is to create my own video player (using Media Playback or something like that) ?

Comment: @OrenKochansky: Either that, or find *one* player that offers what you want, then ask users to install and use it.